# URLSession:didBecomeInvalidWithError: - should completion handler be called?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

If a background transfer gets cancelled and `URLSession:didBecomeInvalidWithError:` is invoked, should we call the completion handler stored by `application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:`?

Answer (score 0):

If your app is in background and `application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:` was called, the completionHandler should also be called, otherwise the system will kill your app

Comment: Ok, so then the answer is yes - if I have a stored completion handler, and the session gets invalidated, I should call it even in didBecomeInvalidWithError?

Comment: Yes, you can test this by running your app, without the debugger (when the debugger is active the system wont kill your app) and looking at the console on XCode>Window>Devices. You'll see that the system will kill your app if you're given background time but never calls the completion handler